# How to handle/schedule a massive event queue created by a javascript for loop

Tags: jquery, queue, jquery-animate

I'm using jquery `animate()` to pull values from svg markup, and create an animation. (IE doesn't support SMIL, so it needs to be done with script.)

Here's the issue: the animation has thousands of elements, each with their own start time, and so the `for` loop I'm using to iterate over each element consumes a few seconds, and even more on slower machines/browsers. So it feels like by the time the event queue actually starts, the runtime has already been chugging for a while, and a few seconds have already passed, so the very beginning of the animation jerks ahead. The animations start at time=zero. *The beginning of the animation is sometimes being clipped off.*

Different browsers seem to handle this differently, and it also seems to depend on the state of the processor, so it's hard for me to figure out systematically what is happening.) Also this is my first foray into both animation and monstruously long runtimes, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong :)

So my specific question is how to avoid this behavior. But more generally, does the event queue's timer start at the beginning of runtime or at the end? How does this work exactly?

Here's most of the relevant code:

```
function runAnimation() {
  // create node list of paths
  var allPaths = document.getElementById('svgcontainer').getElementsByTagName('path');

  // define the animate function
  var doAnim = function(currentPath, dur, begin) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(currentPath).animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 0}, dur);
    }, begin);
  };

  // iterate through the nodelist
  for (var i=0; i<allPaths.length; i++) {

    var pathAnim = allPaths[i].firstChild;

    startTime = parseFloat(pathAnim.getAttribute('begin'));
    pathDuration = parseFloat(pathAnim.getAttribute('dur'));

// change times from seconds to milliseconds        
    startTime = startTime * 1000;
    pathDuration = pathDuration * 1000;

    doAnim(allPaths[i], pathDuration, startTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're expecting a javascript-based animation involving thousands of objects to ever be smooth, you are likely to be disappointed.

Comment: What `event queue timer` are you talking about?  Are you talking about `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @jfriend00: Well, they're consecutive animations, one after another, with some overlap. Not all running at once. On most machines running modern browsers it is very smooth. As a more general point, look at the demo at the bottom of http://www.jstween.org/. Set it to 1000 elements and play it. It's butter-smooth on my machine. It can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because javascript is single threaded, if you start an animation (which probably does a `setTimeout()` for some short period of time in the future) and then you run a bunch of other javascript that takes way, way longer than that first `setTimeout()`, then the `setTimeout()` won't be able to fire/run until after your other javascript is done executing.  When it does finally run, it will realize that holy-cow, it's way, way behind schedule and any decent tweening algorithm will attempt to get back on schedule and skip a bunch of the initial part of the animation.  This sounds like what you describe seeing.

The only way around this is to avoid any significant time of running code after you start the animation because it's that code running that puts the animation behind schedule.  If you were willing to optimize the start-to-end animation process just for this problem and it's your own animation code that you can change, you could run through and initialize every single animation such that all initial state was pre-calculated, but none of the actual animations were started.  Then, once all the code was run to set up all the animations, you'd run one very fast loop to start them all running.  This would minimize the code running time after the first animation was started.

I don't really know what's taking all the initialization time now and haven't benchmarked where the time is really going, but you could optimize your current function like this by precalculating all the initial animation parameters, storing them all into an array and then starting all the animations after you've done all that precalculation like this:

## Idea #1:

```
function runAnimation() {
  // create node list of paths
  var allPaths = document.getElementById('svgcontainer').getElementsByTagName('path');

  // define the animate function
  var doAnim = function(currentPath, dur, begin) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(currentPath).animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 0}, dur);
    }, begin);
  };

  var anims = [];

  // iterate through the nodelist
  for (var i=0, len = allPaths.length; i<len; i++) {

    var pathAnim = allPaths[i].firstChild;

    startTime = parseFloat(pathAnim.getAttribute('begin'));
    pathDuration = parseFloat(pathAnim.getAttribute('dur'));

// change times from seconds to milliseconds        
    startTime = startTime * 1000;
    pathDuration = pathDuration * 1000;

    // accumulate animation parameters, but don't start animation yet
    anims.push([allPaths[i], pathDuration, startTime]);
  }

  // now start all animations as fast as possible
  for (var i = 0, len = anims.length; i < len; i++) {
      doAnim.apply(this, anims[i]);
  }

}
```

To be honest, this code change doesn't look it would be a big savings (there isn't a lot happening in this code that could take lots of time), but if there size of the loop is big, it could be a meaningful improvement.

---

## Idea #2:

Here's another idea.  Sort the animations and call `doAnim()` on the animations with the quickest startTime last.  This makes it less likely that a `setTimeout()` will want to fire while we're still initializing animations.

```
function runAnimation() {
  // create node list of paths
  var allPaths = document.getElementById('svgcontainer').getElementsByTagName('path');

  // define the animate function
  var doAnim = function(currentPath, dur, begin) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(currentPath).animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 0}, dur);
    }, begin);
  };

  var anims = [];

  // iterate through the nodelist
  for (var i=0, len = allPaths.length; i<len; i++) {

    var pathAnim = allPaths[i].firstChild;

    startTime = parseFloat(pathAnim.getAttribute('begin'));
    pathDuration = parseFloat(pathAnim.getAttribute('dur'));

// change times from seconds to milliseconds        
    startTime = startTime * 1000;
    pathDuration = pathDuration * 1000;

    // accumulate animation parameters, but don't start animation yet
    anims.push([allPaths[i], pathDuration, startTime]);
  }

  // sort array so that smallest startTime values are last
  anims.sort(function(a, b) {
      return(b[2] - a[2]);
  });

  // Now start all animations as fast as possible
  // Because the array is sorted, it will start the longer setTimeout()
  // calls first and lessen the chance that the short ones will not get
  // get to fire when they want to
  for (var i = 0, len = anims.length; i < len; i++) {
      doAnim.apply(this, anims[i]);
  }
}
```

Beyond this, any other fixes would probably have to be in the .animate() code itself as it has it's own setup time so if too many objects are all trying to start their animation at the same time, that won't be smooth.

---

## Notes about how SetTimeout() works with the Event Queue:

Here's how `setTimeout()` works with the javascript event queue.  A system timer is scheduled for some time in the future.  When that time is reached, an event for that timer is put into the javascript event queue.  If the javascript engine is idle at that moment, then the corresponding callback is executed immediately.  If the javascript engine is executing something else at the moment, then that timer even just stays in the event queue.  When the currently executing javascript thread finishes its execution, it checks to see if there are any more events in the event queue.  If there is an event waiting, it pulls the oldest one off the queue and starts executing it.  The process repeats until when a javascript thread of execution finishes and there are no more events left in the queue.  While javascript events can only execute one at a time, new events can be added to the queue in real time as the timer events fire (or mouse clicks happen or keys are hit, etc...).

As you can see, because javascript is single threaded, if there are a lot of things to do all at the same time (like lots of animations to start), then only one of those things will actually start on time and all the others will be delayed some.

In your specific code, if your code is trying to start a whole bunch of animations all at the same time (e.g. all with the same or very close startTime values), then you will start the first one, then the second one will get started, the third one started, etc... and while all those others are getting started, the actual animations aren't running yet because their timers to actually show the animations are stuck in the queue beyind all the animations trying to get started.  The key is to minimize the amount of work that has to happen once any animation is running and to try to spread out the work so no large amount of work is getting done all at once.

Comment: Thanks. The DoAnim code is all right there though. The fifth line of the code (!) The `for` loop is iterating over thousands of paths that are in markup. The doAnim function takes three arguments: the path, how long it lasts, and the start time. It's all there.

Comment: Then, my code suggeston should improve things because it will do all `setTimeout()` calls in the `doAnim()` function as close as possible.  If doing it this way still has issues, then you will have to do something differently like add a short delay to every `setTimeout()` so none of them want to fire until after you're done setting them all.  How much that delay would need to be would depend upon the speed of your computer.

Comment: As far as benchmarking, the time is spent reading from the DOM. I see no way around that. You get the general idea, but you say "code is running" without differentiating between the runtime and the queue. (I'm just now learning about this myself, having read Trevor Burnham's new book.) As example: Take at look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xn7yP/ You might well expect "1,2,3" in the console but you get "4,4,4". It's because setTimeout happens in the event queue, which is totally distinct from the runtime, and when the runtime finishes, the variable `i` has been incremented to 4.

Comment: @Ben - I added another code option.  Did you try my first code example yet?

Comment: @Ben - I added some explanation for how `setTimeout()` works with the javascript event queue.

Comment: @Ben - another question for you.  Are lots of `startTime` values the same?  That would lead to a problem because lots of animations would be trying to start at the same time which clogs up the CPU for all the animations already trying to run.

Comment: @Ben - your jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Xn7yP/ has nothing to do with the event queue.  That example is because the function executes some time later AFTER the `for` loop has completed so `i` at that time has the value at the end of the `for` loop, not the value when `setTimeout()` was called.

Comment: +1 for idea #1. I was about to suggest exactly the same and reckon the improvement should be significant because all interaction with the DOM is removed from what is now the second for loop. Even better would be to serve the `begin` and `dur` data directly into javascript (in miliseconds) so they doesn't need to be retrieved from the DOM. Then the initial delay should boil right down.

Comment: @jfriend00: There are some terrific optimization ideas here in terms of speed. I will try building a js array first as an intermediate step. And the paths are listed in markup in the order of their start time, so reversing the order of the for loop might allow me to keep tighter sync on the beginning of the animation by putting it last, at the end of the for loop. Thanks much for that.

Comment: [continued] But I just can't see how that fiddle has nothing to do with the event queue. It's just an illustration of how setTimeout events always happen later than the runtime, even when the time interval is zero. It seems *utterly* relevant. My question, over and over, is: when does event queue's time=0 start? Either: a) When the instance of the loop executes, or b) when the entire runtime is finished? It can't be both. There is only one right answer.

Comment: @Ben - `setTimeout()` ALWAYS run after the current thread of execution finishes, even if you set the timeout value to zero.  Browsers also have a minimum time for `setTimeout()`, often around 13ms.  If you read my note in my answer about how setTimeout() works, that's where I attempted to explain it.

Comment: @jsfriend00: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. But that leads me to my last question (I promise!): When does the "thread of execution" for a `for` loop like this finish? Once with each pass through the loop? Or only at the end of all the loops? Can you define that phrase in this context?

Comment: Javascript runs either at load time or in response to an event.  A "thread of execution" finishes when all load time javascript is done executing or when whatever code that gets called in response to an event handler finishes (e.g. returns from the event handler function).  Your entire function (`for` loop and all) is part of one thread of execution.

Comment: Makes perfect sense as you explain it. But then it raises the obvious question: if the "time=zero" of the event queue only starts when the load time thread is finished, why would tweaking the setTimeouts into a second loop later in that thread (your idea #1) make any difference to when and how those animations are executed? Or is it the simply the case that each setTimeout has its own timer which starts ticking when it's first set into the queue, in the runtime, but that *everything* in the event queue is effectively "held back" until the load time runtimes have finished?

Comment: Also, as a hopefully clarifying example, if I have two scripts linked on a page, and they're indicated to be executed asynchronously, are they still part of a single "thread of execution" or is there a chance that functions put in the event queue by one of the scripts could conceivably fire prior to the execution of the other script?

Comment: `setTimeout()` takes a number of milliseconds from the time you call it.  It doesn't put anything in the event queue UNTIL that number of milliseconds elapses.  Then, an event goes in the queue and will be processed when the javascript interpreter is done running other code and other events in front of it are done.  Doing the short setTimeouts last keeps them from all firing and going in the event queue before your javascript thread is actually done.  That lets them be spread out more like they are intended rather than all piling up on the queue while your loop is running.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12781/discussion-between-jfriend00-and-ben)

Answer (score 0):

What's already been said concerning the performance of animation and JavaScript(jQuery) is unfortunately very true. During my years of trying to find a way to do just such things, I've overcome several obstacles, but in the end it's all the same: `you have to give more than you'll get.`

Here's what you can do about your performance issue, and why you give more than you get.

**The What, How, and Why**

jQuery uses the JavaScript function `setInterval` to update the DOM to reflect the changes in the object. (be it the position, aspect, opacity -- whatever).

The function is re-written in jQuery as step, and step is set to fire every 13 milliseconds. Because you are animating so many objects -- regardless of size, shape, anything -- it's overloading the hell out of the browser.

**What can we do about this, then?**

You have two choices here, and neither of them is an elegant solution for you.

You can either, change the interval at which the animations are fired. While doing this, you would have to take into account the thousands of elements you have, and decide what refresh rate is best for your performance - to - aesthetic ratio.

[$.fx.interval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/)

You should note, though, that some browsers interpret this differently. There are also several plugins which aim to optimize it even more, and some succeed. I don't make recommendations, though, so you'll have to google it to find out.

As a side note, the above will change the queue timers for all animations. If you need it to work on specific animations only, you can google it for a quick answer. This is only objectionaly informative.

**Or**, You can take a snapshot of elements at certain positions, and make them into a larger image that you can manipulate and exchange as needed. This might not work for you if you're using explosions or what not, but generally you can use this solution to get the intended effect.

I hope this has been helpful

Comment: Thanks, but I think you're answering a slightly different question. I'm not asking about jquery's setTimeout interval. I get that its 13. I've read the source. And I'm not animating thousands of elements simultaneously. The animation unfolds over a couple minutes, and only five or so elements are moving at any given time. It works fine once it starts. This isn't a "why isn't my animation smoother?" question. My question is about the nature of the event queue. Please re-read?

Answer (score 0):

Two points :

- Javascript is single-threaded;
- each setTimeout fires a new thread.

Add these two facts together and you can see that your `for` loop is guaranteed to have completed before any of the animations starts to run.

If the `for` loop takes a long time to complete compared with the `startTime` delays then many queued animations will be available to start as soon as the for loop's thread completes - and all the carefully planned micro-timing just went out the window.

Hopefully this offers some insight into the behaviour you describe.

EDIT:

Based on jfriend00's ideas, here is something that will (barring bugs) achieve the same as Idea #2 but avoiding the need for an expensive sort.

```
function runAnimation() {
    var allPaths = document.getElementById('svgcontainer').getElementsByTagName('path'),
        pathAnim, startTime, pathDuration, anims = [],
        i, j, arr;

    function doAnim(i, dur, begin) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(allPaths[i]).animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 0}, dur);
        }, begin);
    }

    // iterate through the nodelist
    for (i = 0, len = allPaths.length; i<len; i++) {
        pathAnim = allPaths[i].firstChild;
        startTime = pathAnim.getAttribute('begin');
        pathDuration = pathAnim.getAttribute('dur');
        // Accumulate animation parameters in such a way that 
        // we avoid the need for an expensive array sort later
        if(!anims[startTime]) {
            anims[startTime] = [];//Allow for multiple events per startTime
        }
        anims[startTime].push([i, pathDuration*1000, startTime*1000]);
    }

    // At this point we have a sparse array indexed by startTime and containing arrays of animation data.
    // To iterate over a sparse array efficiently, we have to do something slightly tricky
    // ref: http://hexmen.com/blog/2006/12/iterating-over-sparse-arrays/
    for (arr in anims) {
        if (String(arr >>> 0) == arr && arr >>> 0 != 0xffffffff) {
            for(j = 0, len = arr.length; j < len; j++) {
                doAnim.apply(this, arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't try to understand the `>>>` stuff in the sparse iterator. I don't fully understand it myself; I just know it works ;-). However I've not used it in a large-volume, time-critical context before so it will be interesting to see if it's fast enough.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what I'm wondering is that your second and third paragraphs actually seem contradictory to me. If the entire for loop is must be totally completed before the event queue starts, why am I seeing the skip-ahead? If that's true, then the length of processing time need to calculate the for loop should be totally irrelevant. The browser plans the animation, and only when it's all ready, it starts it, kicking off the event queue. The for loop could take minutes (theoretically).

Comment: In this scenario, the user should experience an initial delay, but no skip-ahead once things start. In this (i'll call it theory #1), time=0 kicks off when the runtime ends, at the closing script tag, so to speak. But then in your third paragraph (i'll call it theory #2) the processing time is absolutely crucial. In this theory, the timing of the cued events actually begins during the runtime.

Comment: (There are literally thousands of cued events at the end of my runtime. Every second or so, another five animations are kicked off. The start times are staggered.) This really cuts to the heart of what I'm asking in my OP. Does the timing of the event queue start at some moment during the execution of the for loop, or does it start when the loop is finished? It's not obvious to me. I'd like to see a reference. Thanks again.

Comment: All will come clear once you've purged your concept of an "event queue". It's incorrect. SetTimeouts schedule a function to fire at x milliseconds in the future, starting from the moment the setTimout statement is executed. So the clock is ticking on each and every delayed function *independently*. There's no common starting point. In your lengthy `for` loop, those setTimeouts with a short duration will be ready to fire before the loop has finished, and will do so in very short order once the loop (etc.) has finished ... hence what you term "skip ahead".

Comment: Thanks. I get it! I will need some time to wrap my head around the sparse iterator, but it's a really useful tip.

Comment: Aha, the penny has dropped! Now you have to try out jfriend00's two ideas and my one. I'm sure we will both be intrigued to learn of your conclusions.

Comment: I used the double-loop of Idea #1 with a variation of idea #2. The `sort` is unnecessary, but since the first animations in the array are also the first to start, I just reversed the order of the `for` loop, so that the earliest animations get their timers set last. Less chance of a pile-up. Seems to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: OK, that's a good solution for pre-sorted data. Out of interest, have you tried timing the first and second loops?

Comment: Well now you got me curious about the numbers, so I timed them. On my machine running Chrome, the first loop is 75ms, the second 23ms. Zippy. On my crummy testing PC running IE9 the first loop is 429ms, the second 30ms. The PC was where I was seeing the occasional delays, so that makes sense. It actually felt *longer*, but I suppose the numbers don't lie :)

Comment: 23ms/30ms is much better than I was expecting for the second loop. The original machine might have had some other process(es) gobbling up CPU and/or RAM at the time. Virus scans and virus updates are the usual culprits here but potentially anything doing lots of I/O.